# how to play this part of right hand in the image shown? i have no idea how to go about this "two part with one hand"

Tags: piano, practice

[image]

Hello I have a question. I don’t know how to play this part of right hand shown in the image. I would really appreciate some advice on the fingering.
This music is "a letter - by Yukie Nishimura". I am a beginner (late beginner maybe), and self-taught, though I have previously played the violin.

Answer (score 2):

1-2-4, 3, 4, 5, 2-3  perhaps?  A touch of pedal will smooth it out.

Comment: thank you! i tried it now and it is okay. i was going with 1-2-5, because i thought there's no way "4" could do it. but it seems i was not stretching enough since i had no idea how much to stretch (this is my first piece that requires stretching the fingers), and with 1-2-5 i felt it was weird since there was no finger left to play the high Eb so i had to use the 5th again. thank you again sir!

Comment: @vechivara "I had no idea how much to stretch " - a normal size adult hand should be able to play an octave easily with 1-4 as well as 1-5. Octaves fingered 1-4 are easier on the black keys, because there is less chance of accidentally pressing another key at the same time.

Comment: I have to admit I'd probably take the lazy way out, play the first chord 1-2-5 then, with the help of the pedal, hook 4 over for the Eb  :-)

Comment: You could also try 1-2-5 ,3 ,4, 5

Comment: Playing the F#&A with 2&3 is going to be very uncomfortable.